# Calculation of X/Y Coordinates to Offset Y-Rotation of Neighbor

Tags: math, 2d, computational-geometry

I have 2 Lines in 2D Space, defined by L1a/L1b and L2a/L2b, which have the same width (or Length of X) and for simplification Y=0. Both Lines have their rotation axis in their center.
Both lines share a point with the **same coordinates**, namely point L1b from Line 1 and point L2a from Line 2.

**Illustration 1.**

```
L1a-----R1-----L1b L2a-----R2-----L2b
```

Both lines are now being rotated on the Y axis using the same angle, for example 45 degrees.

**Illustration 2.**

```
L1a                L2a
   --                 --
     --                 --
       -R1-               -R2-
           --                 --
             --                 --
               L1b                L2b
```

I'd like to know the necessary calculations to translate the 2 points of either of the lines (pick any you like, if it makes a difference) to make points L1b and L2a share the same coordinates again?

**Illustration 3.**

```
L1a                
   --                 
     --                 
       -R1-               
           --                 
             --                 
               L1b L2a               
                      --
                        --
                          -R2-
                              --
                                --
                                  L2b
```

I hope my illustrations make sense. Remember, L1b and L2a are supposed to have the same coordinates, which is not clearly visible in my illustrations.

Here is an example which doesn't require much mathematical skills.
All points are defined as: **L*(x,y)**

**Example: *Rotation y=90 degrees***

```
L1a(  0,0); L1b(100,0) 
L2a(100,0); L2b(200,0)
```

*Step 1.* Coordinates after rotation

```
L1a( 50,50); L1b( 50,-50)
L2a(150,50); L2b(150,-50)
```

*Step 2.* Translation for points of Line 1

**x=100, y=100**

*Step 3.* Final Coordinates

```
>>L1a(150,150); L1b(150, 50)<<
  L2a(150, 50); L2b(150,-50)
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Just to make sure. It's always the points L1b and L2a which need to share the same coordinates afterwards. For example if the rotation were 180 degrees, using the same starting coordinates, the translation would be **x=200, y=0**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you're description is a bit confusing. You state there is a center of rotation of both lines but the pictures and math both seem to conclude otherwise.

Assuming R1 and R2 the centers of rotation of the lines it sounds like you are just looking for a  circular rotation of all 4 points.  To accomplish this you need to do some trigonometry.

You are going to increment a counter that represents the angle of the point on the circle. Then:

x = radius * cos(angle)

y = radius * sin(angle)

Comment: R1 and R2 are always different, because each of the lines is rotated around their own center. As background info. What I actually rotate are three square shaped images of identical size, which are positioned right next to each other. I want to make it look like if all three images are actually a single image that is being rotated. in order to do that I need to re-position the first and the last image after each of them was rotated the same angle around their own center to make them line up again.

Comment: Sorry but I am still quite confused. Where are the axis of rotation for the lines?

Answer (score 0):

let length=2r;

choose axis so that: 
L1a=(-2r,0) L2a=L1b=(0,0) L2b=(2r,0)

centers are C1=(-r,0) C2=(r,0)

after rotation of x alpha clockwise:
L2a=( r*cos(x)-r , -r*sin(x) ) L1b=( -r*cos(x)+r , r*sin(x) )

So the translation will be:
( 2r-2r*cos(x) , 2r*sin(x) )